# Accessing a JSON array element outside of a Javascript async function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I have the following script:

```
async function getJobs () {
    const response = await fetch('https://redhat.jobs/jobs/feed/json');
    json = await response.json();
    console.log("inside getJobs fuction " + json);
}

jobs = getJobs();
console.log("outside getJobs function" + jobs);
```

The first console.log displays the json response as I would expect. However, with the 2nd log I see `outside getJobs function[object Promise]` in the console.

I think what is happening here is that I need to *wait* for getJobs to run/complete before assigning the results to the `jobs` variable? Or is my approach this entirely wrong to begin with.

Just to give more context, I want getJobs to once, then I want to *do stuff* with the jobs array in the app.

Comment: `jobs = await getJobs();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Should you be returning a value from your function I.e. return json; ?

Answer (score 1):

`fetch(url)` and `response.json()` both return a Promise. What you can do with Promises is use a `.then()` statement. This allows you to execute some code **once the Promise has been resolved**. With regards to your above code, you'll notice if you run it as is, you get:

```
"outside getJobs function[object Promise]"
"inside getJobs fuction [object Object], [object Object], ..."
```

This is because `getJobs()` returns a Promise. So:

```
jobs = getJobs();
console.log("outside getJobs function" + jobs);
```

Executes `console.log()` immediately after it recieves a Promise from `getJobs()`. It's only when that Promise is **resolved** that you'll get anything useful, so you want to make sure you're calling `console.log()` only once the **Promise has been resolved**.

You can do this by using a `.then()` statement. [Learn more about them here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) This allows you to treat this code synchronously. You don't even have to worry about making `getJobs()` async (this can make code slightly more confusing when Promise chaining does the job just fine **in my opinion**). I would implement above like this:

```
function getJobs() {
    var result = fetch('https://redhat.jobs/jobs/feed/json');
    console.log('result inside getJobs is a Promise')
    return(result)
}

getJobs().then(function(response){
  return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(jobs){
  console.log('result after promise chain is ' + jobs)
  }
);
```

Comment: Great answer, however, this is still not really getting at my question. I want a jobs array available outside of any function. So something like: https://gist.github.com/marklocklear/bd0116ff14e266310864e456271a9921. Note I am wanting a jobs array/variable that contains the json output that is outside any other function.

Comment: No problem. You can actually just set jobs = getJobs().then().then(). Your jobs variable will update each time the promise is resolved. You will just have to be aware that until both Promsies are resolved, jobs will be a Promise object and may need to check it's type before actually using it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create another async function in which you call getJobs() with await.
The reason you have `outside getJobs function[object Promise]` is because the console.log is ran before the promise being resolved.

Doing it this way will fix your issue :

```js
async function run(){
  async function getJobs () {
      const response = await fetch('https://redhat.jobs/jobs/feed/json');
      json = await response.json();
      return(json);
  }

  jobs = await getJobs();
  console.log(jobs);
 }
 
 run();
```

Comment: I want `jobs` to be available *outside* the function. Again, this may be a JS thing and not possible.